# Deciding POJO java class for JSON payload after inspecting JSON in list in Retrofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I have a JSON payload coming from the server which is a list of Objects. I need a way to get the response and then check each object for a particular attribute and then decide which POJO object to decode each of those. I have checked StackOverflow and I have come across solutions like :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = response.getBody().toString();
if (checkResponseMessage(json)) {
    Pojo1 pojo1 = gson.fromJson(json, Pojo1.class);
} else {
   Pojo2 pojo2 = gson.fromJson(json, Pojo2.class);
}
```

here the json string is the entire string which is a list of objects, i need to drill down into the list, check an attribute in the object to determine which POJO to use. Any pointers or help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "*I need to drill down into the list*" -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Thanks cricket that works for me!